# What file format can be use to save/access data instead on database

Tags: sql, database, file, installation, format

There is a situation in my company where we are developing a light weight .net web application with least dependencies. Application will be used hosted on client server. However there will not be any internet connection and they will use application locally.

We do not want any type of database installation on client machine. We want to keep it as simple as possible on client side. for this purpose we want to save/access data from file, as data on client side will not exceed more than 100 000 rows. We are also concerned about the speed for accessing data.

Here I want to ask how the data should be saved in file so that it can be accessed fast? What file format should be?

Whether I can use any db file which does not require any database installation on client side.

Comment: From a custom format, through XML to in-process DB libraries (ie. DB is a library shipped with your application) every option is open to you. You need to be far more specific.

Comment: You could may be use Microsoft Access / Microsoft Excel..

Comment: No Internet? So the only Web app feature is that you run it in a browser instead of running it by itself? This seems a bit queer. As to your question: This depends. Once you deal with relations (e.g. items - orders) or with different access (e.g. addresses by name or street or city) then use a zero-configuration database (such as SQLite or Firebird). Once you only store flat data (e.g. addresses always accessed by last name) a simple text file might do.

Answer (score 1):

You could save all data to a json file, this will become increasingly slow and prone to corruption.

Also, have a look at SqlLite.

Comment: I agree with using JSON / XML, since its limited to a max of 1 lac rows, JSON should be fine. Also you could easily query and access JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Sql Compact Edition or SqlLite. Both are file based solution and fit as per your need.

Advantage of using these two would be that you can perform almost all the database queries on it and the data retrieval will be very fast. Also the you can think of optimizing the data storage and create tables etc.

Comment: As per my knowledge SQL Compact is suggested for mobile apps. Can we use it window applications?

Comment: @DevinderSingh:- Indeed, you never mentioned about the windows application instead you mentioned `light weight .net web application` Also how will windows application behave as client server? Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry!, I mean to say can we use SQL Compact in web application as It is suggested for mobile apps in some web sites

Comment: @DevinderSingh:- Yes you can. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173298(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) which is heavily uses in such scenarios (among others used by Chrome and Firefox). It is even public domain, so no license costs etc.

Comment: Can we distribute SQLite with our application without any license? Is there any Licensing Issue in distribution. Can you please provide me a link where I can confirm about the licensing terms

Comment: @DevinderSingh: what part of "public domain" is unclear to you? And just visit the link I've provided in the answer and you will find the license terms.